# I need to know what the highest and lowest pixel between two images in WPF with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, pixel

I have the pixels of each image stored in the Col1 and Col2. How can I know which is the highest pixel and put in a third image?

My definition of highest pixel is as the "por mayor" result in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1_WmoiKgPg

I would also like to know how I can do it for the lowest pixel ("por mayor" in the video).

```
   private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WriteableBitmap imagen1bmp;
    WriteableBitmap imagen2bmp;
    WriteableBitmap imagencombinada;
    int x, y;
    imagen1bmp = (WriteableBitmap)laimagen1.Source;
    imagen2bmp = (WriteableBitmap)laimagen2.Source;


    for (y = 0; y < imagen1bmp.Height; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < imagen1bmp.Width; x++)
        {
            //Get both colors in the pixel point
            Color col1 = LeePixel(imagen1bmp, x, y);
            Color col2 = LeePixel(imagen2bmp, x, y);


        }
        UpdateLayout();
    }
    UpdateLayout();
}
```

Comment: What is your definition of "highest"?

Comment: Comparing pixel values with the raw pixel value rarely makes any sense. Can you explain better what you want to do?

Comment: Ok is in the video on at the beginning of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first thing to do is understanding what is the highest pixel according to your definition. From the result of the video it seems to be a comparison of the raw RGB values. So basically you select the color with the most red then if it is equal the most green then the most blue.

To get the raw value of a `Color`, you need to call the method `toArgb`. One example solution would be:

```
Color col3; //the color for the output image for this pixel
if(col1.toArgb()>col2.toArgb())
    col3=col1;
else
   col3=col2;
```

For the lowest color you just need to exchange `col1` and `col2` in the affectation.

As for the writing the output to another image you seem to have created some customs methods already with that `LeePixel` so I wasn't sure how to do it in a way that would fit in your program.